# How to set a variable equal to null in debug mode within eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Trying to debug a NPE from a remote machine on eclipse, I cannot recreate the test case so wish to set the variable equal to null during runtime within the debug variables however. I am only given two options to set it, to a string (it's type) and via expression. I have tried via expression entering null and = null. However it does not allow me to do it.

edit: I enter

```
null 

=null
```

However I get the error message evaluations must contain either an expression or a block of well-formed statements

Comment: can you paste exact expression in here ?

Comment: Have you tried `(String) null` ?

Comment: @vikingsteve tried it and got the same error as the edit :(

Comment: Perhaps, use IntelliJ? Miles better than Eclipse...

Answer (score 9):

You can use Display View for that. `Windows -> Show View -> Display`

Enter your expression in the Display Tab and execute it. You can see the execute buttons on top right corner with letter J on them.  Simple execute `yourVar = null;`. It should set `yourVar` to null.

Comment: Does you class include generics?

Comment: no it does not. I don't understand why this is being made so difficult. How else does anyone remote debug a NPE if they do not have the test case.

Comment: It googled it and it looks like an eclipse bug. Consider upgrading your eclipse.

Comment: Just want to add, to execute the command you need to do a right-click to show the option of the context menu where you can execute it. Pressing ENTER wont do it like the [Intermediate] window of Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

Click in...

> Window - Show View - Expressions

...and enter `null` for variable.

[image]